# Plugin do perfil LinkedIn na página web

Tags: javascript, html

Caros, gostaria de adicionar o meu perfil do LinkedIn no meu site feito em HTML, achei que era só copiar o código gerado no link: https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/member-profile, porém ao adicioná-lo após o `<body>` nada acontece. 
Alguém saberia informar o modo correto de incluir?

Ele gera um script assim e manda copiar e colar no site:

```
    <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="https://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxxxxx" data-format="inline" data-related="false"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mas é só copiar mesmo. Você pode estar com algum problema devido a segurança. No fiddle, por exemplo, é provável que não aceite pois o conteúdo externo não usa SSL.

Mas se testar no [TryIt do W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic), por exemplo, funciona.

[Veja com o exemplo do meu perfil.](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FGBBAX08UPYX)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="https://www.linkedin.com/in/wurthmann" data-format="inline" data-related="false"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Você pode tentar trocar

```
src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js"
```

por

```
src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js"
```

Ou então, acesse o link https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js e copie o conteúdo do script para ter ele localmente e não depender de conteúdo externo. Feito isso coloque o script no mesmo local do **html** e chame ele assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="NomeDoScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="https://www.linkedin.com/in/wurthmann" data-format="inline" data-related="false"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Parece ser algo relacionado com segurança mesmo, mas não resolveu incluindo o "https://" conforme indicado. Desta forma aparece apenas o icone do LinkedIn e meu nome, não fica como o plugin. Como poderia resolver?

Comment: @nexus, copie o conteúdo do script e salve ele localmente para não depender de conteúdo externo. Coloquei a opção na resposta também.

Comment: Caro, tentei deste modo e não consegui fazer carregar o perfil, mas igual vou validar sua resposta, pois pode ser que funcione para outras pessoas.
Abaixo também vou colocar o link de onde encontrei a solução. Obrigado pelo apoio.

Answer (score 1):

Caros, nao consegui fazer funcionar com a solução acima, mas mesmo assim validei, pois pode ser que funcione para outras pessoas. 
Neste link h[ttps://www.linkedin.com/pulse/personal-branding-tip-how-create-linkedin-badge-your-web-merritt](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/personal-branding-tip-how-create-linkedin-badge-your-web-merritt) segui o passo a passo e funcionou normalmente, caso alguém passe pelo mesmo problema de segurança que eu. 
vlw

Comment: Acho que isso cairia melhor como um comentário nexus, pois não resolve o problema, simplesmente cria de outra forma.